# React updating a state array that is nested within array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, arrayobject

So I'm feeling somewhat confident on updating the array of objects when it's just array of objects using map and the spread function. However, where I'm stuck on is updating an array that is within array of objects.

Here's the example.

I have a seperate state to choose which index

```
const [option, setOption] = useState(0);
```

I initialize the state with array of objects

```
    const [parts, setParts] = useState([
        {bodyPart: "upperLip", price: 1000, active: [false, false, false]},
        {bodyPart: "chin", price: 1000, active: [false, false, false]},
    ])
```

Basically, I want to update the array that is nested in array of objects when the description of bodyPart matches up.

```
    const handleOnClick = (bodyPart) => {            
        
        parts.map((part) => {
            if (part.bodyPart === bodyPart){
                return {...part, active[option]=true}
            } else {
                //do nothing
            }
        })
    }
```

I know that return {...part, active[option]=true} part is incorrect. What would be the proper way of updating this piece within the state?

I've tried to set it to true like I would for an array, but I'm not too sure anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. update state using **setParts** function
2. your **handleOnClick** function would be like this

   ```
    const handleOnClick = (bodyPart) => {            
      setParts((prevState) => {

       //find Index of given bodyPart

       const elementIndex = prevState.findIndex((ele) => ele.bodyPart 
         == bodyPart); 

       // updating data at that particular Index
       prevState[elementIndex] = {

       ...prevState[elementIndex],
       active: [
         ...prevState[elementIndex]. active,
        //adding new active option in that particular bodyPart
        option
        ],
      };
      return prevState; // return the updated data
    }); 

   }
   ```

Explaination of handleOnClick function

- find **Index** value based on *bodyPart* value
- update that particular Index **element**

  - add all the values in that Index element using spread operator

  > ...prevState[elementIndex]

  - Edit **active** property inside that element and assign existing value to it using spread operator

  > ...prevState[elementIndex]. active

  - just add **new** value in active property using comma

  > active: [
  > ...prevState[elementIndex]. active,
  > option
  > ],

  - return the data at the end, means your are returning **updated array**

  > return prevState;